# JSP set javascript variable without hidden input

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring, jsp

I'm looking for a much better way to set a javascript variable in a JSP. I do not like hidden inputs to transfer data to javascript. Is there a better solution you can think of?

Currently on my project, javascript variables are handled via JSP in this fashion:

```
<input id="javaValue" type="number" value="${JAVA_VARIABLE}" class="hidden">
```

Where in the javascript (jQuery) we do the following:

```
var valueFromServer = $("#javaValue").val();
```

However, I feel like this approach is kinda... inelegant. It also causes a problem with the way my project handles 508 compliance, as WAVE will pick up on these fields, and developers are then required to add labels to them.  I'm looking for a better way. I'm already aware of setting variables in their own mini script tag as so:

`<script> value=${JAVA_VARIABLE} </script>`

Are there any drawbacks I'm not seeing with this approach? This seems to be the cleanest and most-simple solution.

I'm also aware I can set them directly on the model and grabbing it using jQuery. That seems like a better approach than option 1, however are there any limitations or problems that could arise from this type of approach?:

`<span id="javaValue" data-value=${JAVA_VARIABLE}>`

Does anyone else have any ideas/opinions on these approaches?

Comment: Can the page just output the value directly in JavaScript code?  Have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You could set a global variable directly like below.

```
 <script>
     var date = '<%= new Date().toString() %>';
     console.log(date);
 <script>
```